# Mysqli fetch array nth row

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I have the following code that fetches a single row:

```
$query = "SELECT *
          FROM translations
          WHERE iddoc = '$id'
          AND submitted = 1;";
$result = mysqli_query($query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

I know this is useful in a while loop, where you can just loop through the results.

But I need to be able to grab specific rows that meet this condition.  Something following this pseudo code:

```
$query = "SELECT *
          FROM translations
          WHERE iddoc = '$id'
          AND submitted = 1;";
$result = mysqli_query($query);
$arrayofrows = mysqli_fetch_arrayofrows($result);
$arrayofrows[0] //(to get the first row)
$arrayofrows[1] //(2nd row)
```

and so on...

How can I do this?

Comment: why not put the extra condition in the Where clause ?

Comment: Is that the best (only) way to do it?  I can't return an array of all of the results?

Comment: [http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php), I guess this should help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
$arrayofrows = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
   $arrayofrows = $row;
}
```

You can now have

```
$arrayofrows[0] //(to get the first row)
$arrayofrows[1] //(2nd row)
```

Comment: OOOH that's sneaaaky.  I could even name it as a function and use it globally.

Comment: `while($arrayofrows[] = mysqli_fetch_array($result))`   or use of `mysqli_fetch_all` would be enough.

Answer (score 3):

I think the function you are looking for is **mysqli_fetch_all** as shown below. This avoids the need to create an extra looping structure or a function to do something already provided.

```
$query = "SELECT *
          FROM translations
          WHERE iddoc = '$id'
          AND submitted = 1;";
$result = mysqli_query($query);
$arrayofrows = mysqli_fetch_all($result);
$arrayofrows[0] //(to get the first row)
$arrayofrows[1] //(2nd row)
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on whether you require the entire result set back or not but I think the LIMIT could be used like:

```
$query = "SELECT *
          FROM translations
          WHERE iddoc = '$id'
          AND submitted = 1 LIMIT 200,200;";
```

Otherwise as others say you will need to convert to an array (which is what `fetch_all` does) and then get the element from that array.

Comment: Thanks @Sammaye, as a matter of fact if only a set of consecutive rows is needed, the `LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]` is perfect