# Starting mysqli_fetch_array from a specific row

Tags: php, mysqli

I have some records, which I use `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()` to iterate on each one of them, then I get some other data from a different table using `while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()`, that is, iterating also on each one of them, then displaying in a HTML table: part of first table data and part of second table data.

However, when I truncate the first table, and then insert new records, the second query `$result2->fetch_assoc()`, starts from the beginning of table and iterates X times, which is basically numbers of rows from first table. This is not what I want, I want to remember the last place of iteration from its table (table 2), then, when called again, only iterate the **remain** rows in the second table, always which is dependent on **n**th times from first table.

I found an answer in stackoverflow, which you can [find it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13556497/mysqli-fetch-array-starting-the-query-on-a-certain-row), however, I didn't understand it correctly: how can you save last LIMIT value, so to start from X id if the `$result2->fetch_assoc()`is called again?

I thought about storing a counter in a text document (which is incremented by first while loop), then use `LIMIT` from that certain number, but I don't really get how to get it work.

Edit: here are some additional info:

Table "aplikimet" schema:

[image: first table schema]

Table "aplikimet_2" schema:

[image: second table schema]

```
$sql = "SELECT id, emri, mbiemri, email, telefoni, vendbanimi, datelindja, mesazhi FROM aplikimet";
$sql2 = "SELECT statusi, uid FROM aplikimet_2";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
if (($result->num_rows > 0) AND ($result2->num_rows>0)){
(html table and th are here)
 while((($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) AND $row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()){
  (html td are here)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It would be better if you showed us the schema for these 2 tables and also the code you are currently running. Then tell us what result your are getting and what result you would like. Its called [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sounds like you should be adding a foreign key in the second table and doing a join to obtain all the data in a single query and then loop once to print it to your html.

Comment: Code is added, including table schemas. 
@solarc I think that'll be a problem since the first table should be truncated, while the second one's data should remain.

Answer (score 0):

every time you call `fetch_assoc()` an internal pointer is incremented. 
after last element the call returns false so your `while(...)` loop will end.

to reset it you can call

```
mysqli_data_seek($result, 0);
```

or

```
$result->data_seek(0);
```

see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php)

IMHO is not a great way to do it.
If you want to loop multiple times the same rowset you can save it in an array after the first complete loop. Then loop with `foreach()` your array all the times you need (your connection can be already closed at that time)

To limit the number of the rows returned by your query use the [SQL LIMIT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp) clause which can have different syntax depending on RDBMS you are using.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, I don't understand exactly what you're trying to say. I don't want to reset the internal pointer of `fetch_assoc()`, rather, I want to save it so when it's called again, it shall start from the saved value, not from the beginning!